# python opencv threshold red image

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, threshold

I am trying to threshold a BGR image after I separate the red channel, but
my code always return "Segmentation fault".

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
def mostrarVentana (titulo, imagen):
  print('Mostrando imagen')
  cv2.imshow(titulo, imagen)
  k = cv2.waitKey(0)
  if k == 27:         # wait for ESC key to exit
     cv2.destroyAllWindows()

img = cv2.imread('RepoImagenes/640x480/P5.jpg', 1)  # loading image in BGR
redImg = img[:, :, 2]  # extracting red channel
rbin, threshImg = cv2.threshold(redImg, 58, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)  # thresholding
mostrarVentana('Binary image', threshImg)
```

I have read the documentation on how to use the threshold() function and I can not figure out what's wrong. I only need to work on the red channel, how can I get this done?

I am using python 3.4 and opencv 3.1.0

Comment: Guessing most likely is file not found...   Use a debugger to see which line fails, and examine variables.

Comment: @Photon The image file is loaded correctly, if I comment the line with the threshold function then the code works correctly, given that I don't call the threshImg variable.

Answer (score 1):

First of all opencv provides a simple API to split `n-channel` image, using `cv2.split()` which would return a list of various channels in the image.

There is also a bug in your `mostrarVentana` method, you have never created a `cv2.namedWindow()` and you are directly referencing to `cv2.imshow()`, but you cannot simply `cv2.imshow()`, without creating a `cv2.namedWindow()`.

Also you must be sure that the image is properly loaded and then access the desired channel, otherwise it would lead to weird errors. Your code with some scenario handling would look like this:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
def mostrarVentana (titulo, imagen):
    print('Mostrando imagen')
    cv2.namedWindow(titulo, cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.imshow(titulo,imagen)
    k = cv2.waitKey(0)
    if k == 27:         # wait for ESC key to exit
       cv2.destroyAllWindows()

img = cv2.imread('RepoImagenes/640x480/P5.jpg', 1)  # loading image in BGR
print img.shape #This should not print error response

if not img is None and len(img.shape) == 3 and img.shape[2] == 3:
    blue_img, green_img, red_img = cv2.split(img)  # extracting red channel
    rbin, threshImg = cv2.threshold(red_img, 58, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)  # thresholding
    mostrarVentana('Binary image', threshImg)

else:
    if img is None:
        print ("Sorry the image path was not valid")
    else:
        print ("Sorry the Image was not loaded in BGR; 3-channel format")
```

Comment: There may be some typos while changing the names of your variables, Kindly review the piece of code.

Comment: The next error appears when I run your code
`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

so I changed the if condition to 
`if img.all() and len(img.shape) == 3 and img.shape[2] == 3:`

After that I have checked the path to the .jpg file and it keeps saying the path is invalid. I have even moved the image to the same directory as the python source code.

Comment: Oh sorry for missing that `img.all()` thing, as far as image path is concerned, you must put a `print img.shape` after the `img = cv2.imread('RepoImagenes/640x480/P5.jpg', 1)`, Also always use full qualified paths like "C:\Downloads\this.png" or "/Users/yourName/Downloads/this.png"

Comment: Is it possible that my opencv binary may be failing? I have tried with both `img.all()` and `img.any()`; the first returns that the image path is not valid and the latter returns `Segmentation fault`. I have also used a full qualified path.

Comment: I have edited the answer to check for image if it is None also pring `img.shape` after loadng the image.

Comment: I print  `img.shape` after reading the image and it gives me the dimentions of such image `(480, 640, 3)`, even then it gives `Segmentation fault`.

Comment: Can you debug the code by placing print statements after each step to track exactly where the seg fault is taking place ?

Comment: I added some print statements in such way


img = cv2.imread('/home/seafire201/Documents/Proyectos/ININ/Tubos/P6.jpg', 1)  # loading image in BGR
print (img.shape)
print(len(img.shape))
print(img.shape[0])
print(img.shape[1])
print(img.shape[2])
if not img is None and len(img.shape) == 3 and img.shape[2] == 3:
    print('before split')
    blue_img, green_img, red_img = cv2.split(img)  # extracting red channel
    print('after split')


and the output is

`(480, 640, 3)`
`3`
`480`
`640`
`3`
`before split`
`Segmentation fault`

Comment: The if condition is being met, but the split function fails.

Comment: Try with another image and see if the seg fault still appears, I guess the image could be corrupted in some way.

Comment: I tried with different images, jpegs and pngs, and it keeps the same. I honestly don't know what else could be wrong.

Comment: Then there may be some problem with installing the various libraries I guess

Comment: The problem was indeed related to the libraries, opencv was not properly installed. I gave up on trying to compile the binaries on opensuse and switched to my ubuntu partition instead.
@ZdaR thanks for your time and support.